# Facing Problem Build Next.js Project with (○ (Static) automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props))

Tags: reactjs, next.js, runtime-error, build-error, npm-build

when i run npm run build Its give me error like:

○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)

```
Route (app)                                Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                      137 B          77.3 kB
└ ○ /favicon.ico                           0 B                0 B
+ First Load JS shared by all              77.1 kB
  ├ chunks/2443530c-d4a6bd7fc7f21e3c.js    50.5 kB
  ├ chunks/488-b4b91b085767513b.js         24.7 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-76d27563e38015d9.js    215 B
  └ chunks/webpack-e30dad67616b08ea.js     1.65 kB

Route (pages)                              Size     First Load JS
─ ○ /404                                   181 B          74.7 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all              74.5 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-8883d1e9be70c3da.js   45.1 kB
  ├ chunks/main-7b5ac83f02b44a6e.js        27.6 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-b555d5e1eab47959.js  195 B
  └ chunks/webpack-e30dad67616b08ea.js     1.65 kB

○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
```

[image]

Anyone face like this type of problem?